# Linear Gradient hard edges in react native

Tags: react-native, expo

Using LinearGradient as a background on my app.
Everything is working and in my iphone it looks great, but on my android simulator the edges are super sharp, is there something I'm missing?

```
<LinearGradient 
  colors={[ colors.bg_gradient_01, colors.bg_gradient_02, colors.bg_gradient_02]} 
  style={styles.container}
  locations={[0, 0.8, 1]} 
>
```

[image]

Comment: Can you add an image of what you face in android?

Comment: @DinhNguyen I added a image now! It's so frustrating, I really can't find a solution...